# RasperryPI remote access

Tags: pi-2, raspberry-pi-os

I recently set up a rasperberryPI for a client, which went well. This raspberryPI has its own wireless network which is used to interact with the device. I've read in threads that it's possible to remotely interact with the device when the device is connected to a "normal" network, but haven't been able to find if this works when the raspberry is hosting its own network.

So in short, if possible how would connect to the raspberryPIs' own wirless network remotely? Do you need to set up a gateway?
Kind regards.

Comment: `connect to the raspberryPIs' own network` wired or wireless?

Comment: Wireless, via wifi.

Comment: well, that's how you connect to the pi - using wifi - wirelessly

Comment: Yes I can see that, but right now the pi is located in a certain room and I can access it via the wifi. But say i want to check the raspberry from home, how would i set up that?

Answer (score 0):

> "I recently set up a rasperberryPI for a client..."

> "...i want to check the raspberry from home..."

What you want to do, it seems, is to access your client's Raspberry Pi remotely, over the Internet. Your client would need to open their internal network up to the Internet, which exposes them to great risk. One way for them to mitigate that risk is to install a VPN, such as [PiVPN](https://www.pivpn.io/) on their Raspberry Pi, then you can securely tunnel into their Pi using either OpenVPN  or WireGuard from your side. This would probably be the safest way to achieve what you want, without allowing the whole world to be able to access your client's Pi device.